# Visual Studio VB.net error to debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working in a solution for a while using Vb.net in Visual Studio, when I try to run debug (F5) I get the following error:
"Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.
The process has been terminated.
Refresh the process list before attempting another attach."

I am not sure what is the issue, but I guess something with Visual Studio, because I restored a backup from my solution that it was working perfectly, and I got the same error (image below). Can you help me please??

[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you turned it off, then back on again?

Comment: Hello, Yes I tried that but it didn't work..... Any suggestions? I guess is something with the database maybe... I have another project that doesnt use a SQL database (it uses only a .txt file) and debug is starting normally.... I don't know...

Comment: any suggestions? I tried to install visual studio again, but the error persisted. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is ancient, but I am experiencing the same issue. Did you ever get it working?